# menu navigatin in GWT with Spring roo

Tags: java, gwt, spring-roo, uibinder

I have created a *GWT* project with `Spring` *Roo*.

The `spring` *Roo* provides tabular list for each entity. But I want to display this list only on clicking a particular `menu item`. (My menu is created in *GWT*).

Please let me know how to achieve this simple functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `Command` or other menu event listeners/action commands and put your code inside the `execute` method of your command class. So that whenever someone clicks on the menu this code block will be executed. Example:

```
Command command = new Command()
{
    public void execute()
    {
        Window.alert("Command Fired");
    }
};

// Top-level menu
MenuBar menutop = new MenuBar();
menutop.addStyleName("demo-MenuItem");

// Item to fire a command
MenuItem fireone = new MenuItem("Fire One", command);

menutop.addItem(fireone);
```

Comment: I am able to do
  Window.alert("Command Fired");
But I wanted a uibinder(ui.xml) file to be shown below the menu instead of window.alert